# как с помощью регулярного выражения найти вхождения в которых цифра больше нуля

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть множество строк

```
_balance":0 
_balance":7
_balance":0
_balance":0.1
_balance":0
_balance":0
```

стоит задача найти строки в которых balance больше нуля

из того что я придумал

```
_balance":[^0]
```

не подходит для дробных чисел

Comment: Если Вам помог какой-то из ответов - отметьте его галочкой как верный. см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

*Дисклеймер:*

> Я не grep-guru и не могу похвастаться лаконичностью своих регулярок.
> В качестве более лаконичного ответа советую [вариант Андрея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1431356/189027)
> Но что-то работающее предложить могу и я.
> Как и объяснить что там к чему.
> Также интересным может быть [вариант ipatev_nn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1431366/189027) с опережающими и ретроспективными проверками

**Замечание #1:**
Как правильно заметил `@Laukhin Andrey`, символьный класс `[^0]` будет содержать абсолютно все символы кроме нуля, в том числе буквы и пр. символы. Поэтому вместо него лучше использовать `[1-9]`

**К решению:**

В регулярном выражении можно использовать символ `|`, который работает как оператор `ИЛИ` и позволяет выбрать одно из двух выражений, находящихся справа и слева от него.

В нашем случае мы выбираем

- **целые больше нуля**
  т.к. числа могут иметь более одного разряда условие на отсутствие нуля оставляем только для первого, при этом второй и дальнейшие разряды опциональны
  Запишем это следующим образом:`[1-9]\d{0,}`
  `[1-9]` - первый символ находится в последовательности от 0 до 9
  `\d{0,}` - второй и последующие являются числами и количество их может быть 0 и более (поэтому мы не указываем верхнюю границу в квантификаторе`{0,}`)
- **дробные с целой частью равной нулю** 
   Записываем следующим образом: `0\.\d+`
- незабываем про **дробные с целой частью больше нуля**
  `[1-9]\d{0,}\.\d+`

Также нужно будет воспользоваться группировкой т.к. мы не хотим неодназначности при поиске регулярных выражений и не хотим чтобы условие ИЛИ нечаянно включило бы _balance в левую часть или же отработало бы по части регулярного выражения.

Поэтому отделяем мухи от котлет, а строковые ключи от численных значений:

`_balance":(внутри группировки условие поиска численного значения)`

и обозначаем границы выбора:
`(целые больше нуля)|(дробные с целой частью равной нулю )|(дробные с целой частью больше нуля)`

Также можно указать, что мы будем искать подходящее выражение до конца строки, чтобы приложение не расслаблялось находя минимально необходимую часть.
Для этого добавим в конце регулярного выражения символ `$`

Применим все вышеописанное и подставим все на свои места

```
_balance":(([1-9]\d{0,})|(0\.\d+)|([1-9]\d{0,}\.\d+))$
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Замечание #2:**
Также `@Владимир Клыков` совершенно верно обратил внимание на то, что выражение `_balance":(([1-9]\d{0,})|(0\.\d+)|([1-9]\d{0,}\.\d+))$` также будет реагировать на `0.0`.
Данный недостаток я заметил еще на стадии написания, но в конкретном кейсе я предпочел принебречь данным обстоятельством, чтобы не раздувать и без того немаленькую регулярку.
Так я решил, потому что строка по которой мы ищем совпадения является выхлопом слаботипизированного языка(такого как php и пр.), в котором `0.0` автоматически будет приводиться к `0` и данное условие в таком случае можно опустить.

Но для других пользователей стоит это учесть.
Проблема в `\d+`, которое может содержать и ноль тоже.
Можно топорно решить добавив еще одно вложенное условие
и заменить `\d+` в `(0\.\d+)` на `([1-9]{1}|\d{2,})`

```
_balance":(([1-9]\d{0,})|(0\.([1-9]{1}|\d{2,}))|([1-9]\d{0,}\.\d+))$
```

либо же, как Laukhin Andrey двигаться в сторону условия наличия хотя бы одного ненулевого символа и опциональном наличии точки.

Comment: Реагирует на ноль ```_balance":0.0```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, да. Думал об этом. В данном случае `0.0` скорее всего к `0` приведется. Во всяком случае то, что я видел в примере говорит именно об этом. Я не хотел и так широкую регулярку захламлять лишним условием. Могу чуть позже добавить замечание и условие на этот случай.

Comment: Еще реагирует, если первый символ - не цифра: `_balance":a.0`

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, это я прошляпил.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Поправьте немного, ведь такой содержательный ответ получился. Плюсиком тоже не обижу ;)

Comment: да, я поправлю через полчасика как до места рабочего доберусь

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, ну до рабочего минимума я его точно довёл, а дальше - уж пусть сам выбирает. у него тут достаточно выбора теперь)

Answer (score 1):

```
_balance":([1-9]\d*\.?\d*|\d\.\d*[1-9]\d*)
```

Либо первая цифра от 1 до 9, а за ней любые цифры (допуская точку), либо первая цифра 0, тогда мы ожидаем точку, а за ней должна быть хотя бы одна ненулевая цифра.

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/VDRirG/1)

Comment: плюсик вам за это

Answer (score 1):

Так как ЯП не указан, приведу пример для JS:

```
(?<![\d.-])(0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|\d*[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?)(?![\d.-])
```

```js
const regex = /(?<![\d.-])(0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|\d*[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?)(?![\d.-])/gm;

const str = `_balance":0 
_balance":7
_balance":0.0010
_balance":0.1
_balance":0.0
_balance":00
_balance":01
_balance":02.13
_balance":1234.1234
_balance":00.13
_balance":-1`;
        
 console.log(str.match(regex));
```

`(?<![\d.-])` - негативный просмотр назад, где нет символа цифры, точки или тире
`(0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|...)` - если вначале `0.` то проверяем что бы в цифрах после точки была хоть одна отличная от нуля
`(...|\d*[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?)` - в случае если цифра до точки выше нуля, то необязательной группой будет является часть после точки, т.е. `1.01` и `1` будут считаться валидными
`(?![\d.-])` - негативный просмотре вперед что символ после захвата не будет являться цифре, точке или тире.

Comment: опережающим и ретроспективным проверкам, наверное, нужно чуточку больше внимания уделить и хотя бы сформулировать как они работают и что делают.